# How to use an intent to update an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have a service that is downloading a file. When the download is done, I would like to update my "Downloaded files" list in my `Activity`, but only if the `Activity` is running. I do not want the `Activity` to start if it's not already running.

I was hoping I could do this by making a new `Intent` with some special flag.

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? A tiny code example maybe?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create new BroadcastReceiver instance and do something along these lines on your Activity's onResume() method:

```
registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadService.ACTION_FILE_DOWNLOADED));
```

After that, override myReceiver's onReceive() method to call a function that updates the component you want:

```
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
...
    updateViewWithData(service.getNewFileData());
...
}
```

On your Activity's onPause() method, just unregister the receiver:

```
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
```

I hope that this would help you, feel free to ask if there is something unclear.

Comment: This is very good way of communication. But what to do in case results were delivered, when activity was in paused state? So after onResume activity can wait a long time for results. And no data will be received, because data were missed.

Answer (score 3):

The good way to do this is to bind your "Downloaded files" activity to the service. When you bind the service, in the function onServiceConnected, register a Binder callback. Then, whenever you have new data available, service just calls that callback. If the activity is not running, the callback list at the service side will be empty, so it will not inform your activity.

For an example of this approach, take a look at RemoteService.java in Android SDK:

samples\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app\

Comment: What would be the advantage of this, compared to intent messaging like Dimitar Dimitrov proposed? Thanks