# When should super.onResume() be called?

Tags: android

When should `super.onResume();` be called, on the first line of `onResume()` or on the last line?

```
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "On Resume");
    super.onResume();
    displayDashboard();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether or not you choose to call the super method depends upon whether you require the inherited functionality. You can often find out if you need to call the super method from Api documentation.

Sometimes you need to do something before the super method is called (ie filter an attribute or perform an action). Sometimes your code has to happen after the super method has executed.

It is very much implementation specific.

Comment: The documentation reads "Note: Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work, as shown in the examples above.". From your answer I understand you need to break that rule sometimes?

Comment: Super method should always be called when documentation explicitly says so. You can usually choose what to do before and after the super call however. When overriding a base method you should always have an understanding of the way in which that method works. Whether or not you choose to call the super method depends on a) if you must (ie documentation says to) or b) you want base functionality. The quote in your comment indicates that particular circumstance requires the super method to be called prior to any custom processing @arne

Comment: It just says "always". I didn't find any particular precondition in the docs.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it actually does. It say "Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work". To me this means that super() should be called as the first statement in your overridden function.

Answer (score 16):

Android’s source code can tell us everything. If you check the Activity super class you can find the following lines:

```
protected void onResume() {
    if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Slog.v(TAG, "onResume " + this);
    getApplication().dispatchActivityResumed(this);
    mCalled = true;
}
```

On this basis, no matter before or after it is called.

Answer (score 0):

there is an example on the following link:

> [Android -- How to properly handle onPause/onResume methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691570/android-how-to-properly-handle-onpause-onresume-methods)