# Redirect user once app is opened - Android

Tags: android

I am working on a Android App and what I want to happen is simply, when user select's app it will open up the browser to a specified webpage.  Right now I have the following on the `onCreate`:

```
Intent viewIntent =
                new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                  Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
```

The problem with this is, when the app first loads it works but once I try clicking on it again and such, it just opens the app.  I am trying to figure out how to make it that, whenever the app is opened it will redirect the user and close the app.

Suggestions and ideas?

UPDATE:

Here is the `resume()` function I placed on top to see what would happen, it seems to work but tells me it has stopped working and than opens web browser.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //start new activity
        Intent viewIntent =
                new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                  Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried overriding onResume()?

Comment: That seems to be working but it tells me: `error, application has stopped working`

Comment: I hope you didn't forget to add `super.onResume();` first and then call the rest of it.

Comment: Ops :P but hey why would I have to call the parent of onResume?

Comment: [android - When should super.onResume() be called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225958/when-should-super-onresume-be-called)

Comment: Thanks man, give awnser and I will give you point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to finish your app after launching the intent.
You might want to spawn a new task too.

```
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
  viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(viewIntent);
  finish();
}
```