# How to get window from a Service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I made a `View` without an `Activity` by using the `WindowManager`.

I want to change the state of the view like below:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

but I cannot use `getWindow()` in a `Service`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Services don't have a UI. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know service can not have a UI.
But I made it by using addView() && surfaceView.

Comment: That doesn't actually create a user interface; it just creates a couple of View objects. I'll repeat my question: what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to make a user can see the state bar.
I mean sometimes.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @DuckJinJeon I wanted to do the same process as you specified in the question, But what i wanted to understand how did you create a service using  using addView() without any layouts i have refereed the answer below and it looks good to me but just the   mRootView part is creating problems-- Thanks anyways

Comment: I am having this same issue!

Answer (score 7):

You **can't** get a window in a Service. But you **can** use **[WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)** to add a view(root) as you did already.

And You can also update view through [**updateViewLayout**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#updateViewLayout%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), you can change your window's status(window type, flag, x, y, w, h, gravity, etc...) like below codes.

```
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;
..........

//let's assume that an event occurred
if(mConfiguration.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    mLayoutParams.screenOrientation=Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
}
mLayoutParams.softInputMode=WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN;

mLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER; 
int flag=0
            |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN
            |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
            ; 
mLayoutParams.flags=flag;

mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mRootView, mLayoutParams);
```

Comment: how to get mRootView ?

Comment: @quicklearner mRootView is your own view instance that you'd have previously added via mWindowManager.addView()

Answer (score 1):

As per Service doesn't have UI, You have to start activity from it to getWindow() attribute..

**Either make a Transparent activity or just start activity, getWindow() and immediately finish it..** I think you have to make a transparent activity. (This is my personal opinion)

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But I can not start Activity. I just have to change the mode Full <->not Full in service.

Comment: If you want to get Window attribute then I think anyhow you have to use Activity..

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, I gather, is have the service signal that a change should be made in the appearance of an activity. The way to do this is for the service to broadcast an intent using `Context.sendBroadcast(Intent)` and for your activity to respond in it's `onReceive` method. The accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324307/how-to-use-an-intent-to-update-an-activity) has more details about how to set this up.